# Oracle replication process error ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run script RMAN for replication database oracle its return error

```
connected to auxiliary database (not started)
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 08/11/2016 14:16:44
RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
RMAN-04014: startup failed: ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
Additional information: 9925
```

I sow adump directory permissions and owners there were everything okay

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `audit_file_dest` parameter defined, and has sufficient permissions, especially writeable ?

Moreover, your disk, which holds that directory's files, should have enough space.